# What to do when app crashes and Qt Creator (GDB) won't give backtrace?

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

My Qt app is crashing, with no output but this:

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

When I run it in the debugger, it also crashes really fast and the stacktrace pane in Qt Creator is empty. Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: You can use lldb or gdb from the command line, without Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

I would try breaking apart your code and testing sections of it, so you can at least narrow the issue down. Saying it crashes really fast doesn't exactly give enough context for us to provide solutions.

Comment: Does it crash instantly upon executing?

Comment: "I would try breaking apart your code and testing sections of it" - sure, that's a last resort solution, but I'd rather use a better way, such as making the debugger work properly somehow. "Does it crash instantly upon executing?" - yes.